# To pass the images via http url in sikuli

Tags: java, sikuli, sikuli-script

I just like to know, is there any way the user can pass the images via HTTP url in sikuli ?. I tried by using `ImagePath.addHTTP("https://drive.google.com/");` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure I understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: I need to pass the images to Sikuli using the http  url not by the folder path.